# search feature in jquery Select2 function is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

the code is running as intended but the select2 function is not working. Don't get any error or anything just the search option is not there

```
<?php
require 'dbConfig.php';
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>[enter image description here][1]
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="JtLogo.ico" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="JtLogo.ico" sizes="16x16">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#d9230f">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400italic,500,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elephant.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/application.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">  
  </style>
</head>
<body style="padding: 0%;">
  <div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; background-color: white; padding: 4px;"><div class="row gutter-xs" style="background-color: #029ACF;">
    <div style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px;"><font style="color: #FFF;">SAMPLE TRACK (KOLKATA)</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row gutter-xs" style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" style="margin-left: 5px;" onclick="window.location='home.php';">HOME</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="margin-right: 5px; float: right;" id="logout" onclick="window.location='logout.php';"><span class="icon icon-sign-out" style="line-height: 18px;"></span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="margin-right: 0px; float: right;" disabled="">
    LOGOUT
    </button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row gutter-xs">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="cbosale" id="cbosale" required>
        <option value="">Select Sale</option>
        <?php
        echo $sql1 = "SELECT Query";
        $res1 = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);
        $i1 = 0;
        while($r1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1))
        {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $r1[0]; ?>"><?php echo $r1[0]; ?>/<?php echo $r1[1]; ?></option>
        <?php $i1++; } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="cbogarden" id="cbogarden">
        <option value="">Select Garden</option>
        <?php
        echo $sql1 = "SELECT Query";
        $res1 = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);
        $i1 = 0;
        while($r1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1))
        {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $r1[0]; ?>"><?php echo $r1[0]; ?></option>
        <?php $i1++; } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row gutter-xs">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="cbocat" id="cbocat" required>
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT Query"; 
        $res = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $i = 0;
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $r[0]; ?>"><?php echo $r[0]; ?></option>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
    <div id="showgrade">
      <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="cbograde" id="cbograde">
        <option value="">Select Grade</option>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT Query"; //GradeCode CategoryCode GardenCode 
        $res = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $i = 0;
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $r[0]; ?>"><?php echo $r[0]; ?></option>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
    <div class="row gutter-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="filter">SHOW</button>
        </div>
        
    </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="row gutter-xs">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="cmail.php">E-Mail Selected DATA</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="catalogue_save_exl.php">Download SELECTION</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <div class="row gutter-xs" style="margin-top: 155px; padding: 4px;">
    <div id="showdata">
      <div id="postList">

      </div>
        
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#filter').click(function(){
          var sale = $('#cbosale').val();
          var cat = $('#cbocat').val();
          var grade = $('#cbograde').val();
          var garden = $('#cbogarden').val();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'catalogue_data.php',
            data: 'sale='+sale+'&cat='+cat+'&grade='+grade+'&garden='+garden,
            success: function(html){
              $('#postList').html(html);
            }
          });
        });
      });
      
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#cbocat').change(function(){
                var ttype = $('#cbocat').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'get_grade.php',
                    data: 'ttype='+ttype,
                    success: function(html){
                        $('#showgrade').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
          
          $(document).ready(function () {
  $("select").select2();
});
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

please check the below link to see the output.

The main functionality if the website is working and has no issues, it's just the select2 function this is not working

Comment: `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` is wrong, `manifest` isn't valid value for `rel` attribute.

Comment: Also you downloading 1.9.1, 3.3.1 & 3.5.1 versions of jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code:

```
<?php
require 'dbConfig.php';
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <title></title>[enter image description here][1]

    <!-- Icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="JtLogo.ico" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="JtLogo.ico" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#d9230f">

    <!-- Manifest -->
    <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"> -->

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400italic,500,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elephant.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/application.min.css">

    <!-- BootStrap & Select2 CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" />

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery Mobile -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap & Select2 JS -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="padding: 0%;">
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; background-color: white; padding: 4px;">
        <div class="row gutter-xs" style="background-color: #029ACF;">
            <div style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px;">
                <font style="color: #FFF;">SAMPLE TRACK (KOLKATA)</font>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row gutter-xs" style="margin-top: 5px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" style="margin-left: 5px;" onclick="window.location='home.php';">
                HOME
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="margin-right: 5px; float: right;" id="logout" onclick="window.location='logout.php';">
                <span class="icon icon-sign-out" style="line-height: 18px;"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="margin-right: 0px; float: right;" disabled="">
                LOGOUT
            </button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row gutter-xs">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="cbosale" id="cbosale" required>
                    <option value="">Select Sale</option>
                    <?php
                    echo $sql1 = "SELECT Query";
                    $res1 = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);
                    $i1 = 0;
                    while($r1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $r1[0]; ?>"><?php echo $r1[0]; ?>/<?php echo $r1[1]; ?></option>
                        <?php $i1++; } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                    <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="cbogarden" id="cbogarden">
                        <option value="">Select Garden</option>
                        <?php
                        echo $sql1 = "SELECT Query";
                        $res1 = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);
                        $i1 = 0;
                        while($r1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1))
                        {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $r1[0]; ?>"><?php echo $r1[0]; ?></option>
                            <?php $i1++; } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row gutter-xs">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                        <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="cbocat" id="cbocat" required>
                            <option value="">Select Category</option>
                            <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT Query"; 
                            $res = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                            $i = 0;
                            while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                            {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $r[0]; ?>"><?php echo $r[0]; ?></option>
                                <?php $i++; } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                            <div id="showgrade">
                                <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="cbograde" id="cbograde">
                                    <option value="">Select Grade</option>
                                    <?php
                                    $sql = "SELECT Query"; //GradeCode CategoryCode GardenCode 
                                    $res = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                                    $i = 0;
                                    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                                    {
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $r[0]; ?>"><?php echo $r[0]; ?></option>
                                        <?php $i++; } ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="row gutter-xs">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="filter">SHOW</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="row gutter-xs">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="cmail.php">E-Mail Selected DATA</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="catalogue_save_exl.php">Download SELECTION</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                    <div class="row gutter-xs" style="margin-top: 155px; padding: 4px;">
                        <div id="showdata">
                            <div id="postList">

                            </div>

                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                    $('#filter').click(function(){
                                        var sale = $('#cbosale').val();
                                        var cat = $('#cbocat').val();
                                        var grade = $('#cbograde').val();
                                        var garden = $('#cbogarden').val();
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            url: 'catalogue_data.php',
                                            data: 'sale='+sale+'&cat='+cat+'&grade='+grade+'&garden='+garden,
                                            success: function(html){
                                                $('#postList').html(html);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                });

                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                    $('#cbocat').change(function(){
                                        var ttype = $('#cbocat').val();
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            url: 'get_grade.php',
                                            data: 'ttype='+ttype,
                                            success: function(html){
                                                $('#showgrade').html(html);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                });

                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                    $("select").select2();
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: It's working now. could you point out the mistakes I made, please

Comment: Instead of checking 3 times, put `$('#filter').click(function()`, `$('#cbocat').change(function()` and ` $("select").select2();` inside first `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: Also move <script> tags which importing Bootstrap, Select2, your JavaScript at the end of <body> tag. This make your page load faster. But don't alter the sequence jQuery -> jQuery Mobile -> Bootstrap JS -> Select2 JS -> your external JS -> other <script> tags